# SQL Calculating Changes Within a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have data from an accelerometer which measures activity levels – the output is given as number of seconds in each minute spent standing or lying (see table below for an example from 1 individual).

```
**Date**   **Time**  **Standing** **Lying**
21/02/2017  10:15:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:16:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:17:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:18:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:19:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:20:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:21:00    43     17
21/02/2017  10:22:00    60     0
21/02/2017  10:23:00    60     0
21/02/2017  10:24:00    46     14
21/02/2017  10:25:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:26:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:27:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:28:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:29:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:30:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:31:00    0      60
21/02/2017  10:32:00    0      60
```

I am interested in how activity changes for each individual on a day by day basis. So interested in calculating the number of times the patient changes from lying to standing in a 24 hr period – e.g. how many times does a period of lying occur in 24 hrs – but with a threshold for 60s included. For example if the data changes from lying to standing for only a number of seconds then it is likely false.

A second thing I’d be interested in doing is calculating the average time each (true) lying bout is for, again in a 24 hr period within each individual.

What would be the best approach within SQL Server for each?

**EDIT**

Question above is too broad. I want to know the best way to calculate total number of lying bouts AND the average length of lying bout - both in a 24 hr period

A Transition would be anything that changes from lying to standing (e.g. 10:21:00 on the table) or the reverse - standing to lying (e.g. 10:24:00)

```
Date Bouts AvBoutTime 
21/2 41    20 
22/2 38    25 
23/2 48    17
```

Comment: "Another thing" generally means the question is too broad.  I would also suggest that you provide the results that you want from the data you have provided.  You should also explain that it means to transition between standing and lying, because it is not obvious given the data you have provided.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Many thanks - information has been updated above.

Comment: Can you include sample output based on example data provided?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze output would be number of lying "bouts" within a 24 hr period. Example of what ideally I'd be looking for below (also updated above)

Date  Bouts AvBoutTime
21/2    41      20
22/2    38     25
23/2    48     17

Comment: In your sample data, the period from 10.15 to 10.21. Is this one bout or 6? And period 10.21 to 10.24, is this 0 bouts or 2?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze 10:15 to 10:21 would be 1 bout (position hasn't changed), and 10:21 to 10:24 would be 0. Bout #2 would then be 10:24 to sometime after 10:32

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I have only a partial answer here but I'll post it in case it helps and I might look into it if I have additional ideas.

Here is what I have plus the link to the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72532/27/0

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE Activity (
  [Date] varchar(10),
  [Time] varchar(8),
  [Standing] Integer,
  [Lying] Integer
);


INSERT INTO Activity ([Date], [Time], [Standing], [Lying])
VALUES
('21/02/2017', '10:15:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:16:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:17:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:18:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:19:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:20:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:21:00', 43, 17),
('21/02/2017', '10:22:00', 60, 0),
('21/02/2017', '10:23:00', 60, 0),
('21/02/2017', '10:24:00', 46, 14),
('21/02/2017', '10:25:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:26:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:27:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:28:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:29:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:30:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:31:00', 0,  60),
('21/02/2017', '10:32:00', 0,  60)
;
```

**Intermediate Table**

I have created an intermediate table where I pivoted the data into a `CurrentPosture` and `Duration` columns. I have also added a `PreviousPosture` column to be able to track the changes.

```
CREATE TABLE ActivityPivoted (
  [Date] varchar(10),
  [Time] varchar(8),
  [Duration] Integer,
  [CurrentPosture] varchar(20),
  [PreviousPosture] varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO ActivityPivoted
select Date,
Time,
Duration,
CurrentPosture,
lag(CurrentPosture, 1, 'N/A') over(order by Time) as 'PreviousPosture'
from (
    select *,
    case when Standing>Lying then 'Standing' else 'Lying' end as CurrentPosture,
    case when Standing>Lying then Standing else Lying end as Duration
    from Activity
) tmp
order by Time
```

Here is what it contains:

```
|       Date |     Time | Duration | CurrentPosture | PreviousPosture |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|-----------------|
| 21/02/2017 | 10:15:00 |       60 |          Lying |             N/A |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:16:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:17:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:18:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:19:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:20:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:21:00 |       43 |       Standing |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:22:00 |       60 |       Standing |        Standing |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:23:00 |       60 |       Standing |        Standing |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:24:00 |       46 |       Standing |        Standing |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:25:00 |       60 |          Lying |        Standing |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:26:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:27:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:28:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:29:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:30:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:31:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:32:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying |
```

From there, it's acutally quite easy to count the number of posture changes

```
select CurrentPosture,
count(*)
from ActivityPivoted
where CurrentPosture<>PreviousPosture
group by CurrentPosture
```

Result

```
| CurrentPosture |   |
|----------------|---|
|          Lying | 2 |
|       Standing | 1 |
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to sum the duration for each posture partition because SQL Server is not resetting the sum over the partition. Example:

```
select *,
sum(Duration) over(partition by CurrentPosture order by Time)
from ActivityPivoted
order by Time
```

Result:

```
|       Date |     Time | Duration | CurrentPosture | PreviousPosture |     |
|------------|----------|----------|----------------|-----------------|-----|
| 21/02/2017 | 10:15:00 |       60 |          Lying |             N/A |  60 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:16:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 120 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:17:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 180 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:18:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 240 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:19:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 300 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:20:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 360 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:21:00 |       43 |       Standing |           Lying |  43 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:22:00 |       60 |       Standing |        Standing | 103 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:23:00 |       60 |       Standing |        Standing | 163 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:24:00 |       46 |       Standing |        Standing | 209 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:25:00 |       60 |          Lying |        Standing | 420 | < Sum not reset
| 21/02/2017 | 10:26:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 480 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:27:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 540 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:28:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 600 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:29:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 660 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:30:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 720 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:31:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 780 |
| 21/02/2017 | 10:32:00 |       60 |          Lying |           Lying | 840 |
```

Comment: It's useful having the current/previous posture. However I'm having trouble replicating it as the 2008 version of SQL doesn't seem to have a lag function

Answer (score 0):

This is a ***Gaps and Islands*** question

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE ([Date] DATE, [Time] TIME, Standing INT, Lying INT )
INSERT INTO @tab
(Date, Time, Standing, Lying)
VALUES
('2017-02-21','10:15:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:16:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:17:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:18:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:19:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:20:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:21:00',43,17),
('2017-02-21','10:22:00',60,0),
('2017-02-21','10:23:00',60,0),
('2017-02-21','10:24:00',46,14),
('2017-02-21','10:25:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:26:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:27:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:28:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:29:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:30:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:31:00',0,60),
('2017-02-21','10:32:00',0,60)

SELECT 
      Y.[Date]
    , Bouts     = COUNT(DISTINCT Y.Island) --DISTINCT Islands for number of bouts
    , AvBoutTime=CAST((SUM(Y.Lying)/ (COUNT(DISTINCT Y.Island)* 1.0) ) AS DECIMAL(9,1))
FROM
(
    SELECT
            --Break the dataset down into ISLANDS- using the funky technique
          Island = X.RN - ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY X.Date ORDER BY X.RN)
        , X.[Date]
        , X.[Time]
        , X.Standing
        , X.Lying
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
                --CREATE AN INCREMENTING ID Column like an Identity using ROW_NUmber
                --No need for this if there's already is one just missing from the example shown
              RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.[Date] ORDER BY T.[Time] ASC)
            , T.[Date]
            , T.[Time]
            , T.Standing
            , T.Lying 
        FROM @tab T
    ) X
    WHERE X.Lying > 0
) Y
GROUP BY
      Y.[Date]
ORDER BY [Y].[Date]
```

Output

```
Date        Bouts   AvBoutTime
2017-02-21  2       435.5
```

Comment: This works well for calculating the number of bouts. However AvBoutTime seems to be average of each row (which will always be ~60), rather than the average value of each bout. In other words it would be the average of the sum of each bout that I'd wanting to calculate.

For example using the table above, bout #1 lasted 377s and bout #2 lasted 494s, which would give AvBoutTime of 435.5.

Comment: @JB32 I misunderstood your comment answer above about what is and what isn't a bout. Anyway, I have edited the answer now